# How to apply value_counts() to multiple columns in polars python?

Tags: apply, python-polars

I am trying to `apply` a simple `value_counts()` to multiple columns on a `dataframe` in polars but getting error.

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
```

data:

```
sample_df = pl.DataFrame({'sub-category': ['tv','mobile','tv','wm','micro','wm'],
              'category': ['electronics','mobile','electronics','electronics','kitchen','electronics']})
```

Failed Attempts:

```
#1
sample_df.apply(value_counts())

#2
sample_df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

#3
sample_df.apply(lambda x: x.to_series().value_counts())

#4
sample_df.select(pl.col(['sub-category','category'])).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

#5
sample_df.select(pl.col(['sub-category','category'])).apply(lambda x: x.to_series().value_counts())
```

But if I convert it to `Pandas` dataframe then it works:

```
sample_df.to_pandas().apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
```

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? Is it an invidual count per column? Something like: `sample_df.melt().select(pl.struct(pl.all()).value_counts())`

Comment: @jqurious I am trying to get values for individual counts for each columns like this `pandas` code `sample_df.to_pandas().apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())` gives me that sort of output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could reshape with [`.melt()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html)

```py
shape: (12, 2)
┌──────────────┬─────────────┐
│ variable     ┆ value       │
│ ---          ┆ ---         │
│ str          ┆ str         │
╞══════════════╪═════════════╡
│ sub-category ┆ tv          │
│ sub-category ┆ mobile      │
│ sub-category ┆ tv          │
│ sub-category ┆ wm          │
│ sub-category ┆ micro       │
│ …            ┆ …           │
│ category     ┆ mobile      │
│ category     ┆ electronics │
│ category     ┆ electronics │
│ category     ┆ kitchen     │
│ category     ┆ electronics │
└──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

In which case it is then the length of each group:

```py
df.melt().group_by(pl.all()).len()
```

```py
shape: (7, 3)
┌──────────────┬─────────────┬─────┐
│ variable     ┆ value       ┆ len │
│ ---          ┆ ---         ┆ --- │
│ str          ┆ str         ┆ u32 │
╞══════════════╪═════════════╪═════╡
│ category     ┆ kitchen     ┆ 1   │
│ sub-category ┆ tv          ┆ 2   │
│ sub-category ┆ mobile      ┆ 1   │
│ category     ┆ mobile      ┆ 1   │
│ sub-category ┆ wm          ┆ 2   │
│ sub-category ┆ micro       ┆ 1   │
│ category     ┆ electronics ┆ 4   │
└──────────────┴─────────────┴─────┘
```

[`.pivot()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#polars.DataFrame.pivot) can be used to reshape into individual columns if required.

```py
(df.melt()
   .pivot(
      index = "value",
      columns = "variable",
      values = "value",
      aggregate_function = pl.len()
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────┐
│ value       ┆ sub-category ┆ category │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---      │
│ str         ┆ u32          ┆ u32      │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪══════════╡
│ tv          ┆ 2            ┆ null     │
│ mobile      ┆ 1            ┆ 1        │
│ wm          ┆ 2            ┆ null     │
│ micro       ┆ 1            ┆ null     │
│ electronics ┆ null         ┆ 4        │
│ kitchen     ┆ null         ┆ 1        │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: I edited the pivot parameter order so that it matches the order that you'd use if you weren't using named arguments, ie `pivot('counts','value','variable','first')`

Answer (score 1):

So if you want the same result like in the pandas case you have to do a small work around, which I think pandas does implicit since it is based on an index.

So you create for each column a value count and then merge them with an outer join.

```
def multiple_column_value_counts(df, columns, value_column = "values"):
    value_counts_dfs = []
    for column in columns:
        counts = df.get_column(column).value_counts()

        name_map = {k: v for k, v in zip(counts.columns, [value_column, column])}
        value_counts_dfs.append(counts.rename(name_map))

    merge_df = value_counts_dfs.pop(0)

    for value_counts in value_counts_dfs:
        merge_df = merge_df.join(value_counts, on = value_column, how = "outer")
    return(merge_df)


columns = ['category', 'sub-category']

multiple_column_value_counts(sample_df, columns)



shape: (6, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ values      ┆ category ┆ sub-category │
│ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---          │
│ str         ┆ u32      ┆ u32          │
╞═════════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
│ micro       ┆ null     ┆ 1            │
│ mobile      ┆ 1        ┆ 1            │
│ wm          ┆ null     ┆ 2            │
│ tv          ┆ null     ┆ 2            │
│ kitchen     ┆ 1        ┆ null         │
│ electronics ┆ 4        ┆ null         │
└─────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks @alexp for sharing the solution but this quite large & complex way of `polars` to do something that `pandas` can do in just 1 line of code: - `sample_df.to_pandas()[['sub-category','category']].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())` . And I agree with you but will still wait to see if there could be any other better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: one line answer at the bottom**

I think it's worth pointing out that polars is not something built on top of pandas or with any intent of sharing its API and syntax. Additionally, while pandas makes extensive use of `df.apply`, in polars that is almost always suboptimal if not just wrong.

To your question. polars does have a [`value_counts`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.value_counts.html#polars-expr-value-counts) method, although it returns a `struct` which is another thing that is very different from pandas.

Let's say we have

```
df=pl.from_repr("""shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 1   │
│ 3   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┘""")
```

then if you just wanted to go one column at a time you could do

```
df.select(pl.col('a').value_counts()).unnest('a')
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ counts │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2      │
│ 3   ┆ 2      │
│ 2   ┆ 2      │
└─────┴────────┘
```

There's not a great way of making that work for all columns. You could do:

```
f= lambda x:df.select(pl.col(x).value_counts()).unnest(x).rename({x:'value','counts':x}).lazy()
final=f(df.columns[-1])
for x in df.columns[:-1][::-1]:
    final=f(x).join(final, on='value',how='outer')
final.collect()
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬──────┐
│ value ┆ a   ┆ b    │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64   ┆ u32 ┆ u32  │
╞═══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2   ┆ 3    │
│ 2     ┆ 2   ┆ 3    │
│ 3     ┆ 2   ┆ null │
└───────┴─────┴──────┘
```

definitely awkward although this is probably more performant than the next approach which is much more succinct to type.

```
df.melt().groupby('variable','value').count().pivot('count','value','variable','first')
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the things with single column value_counts struct `unnest` and the working with whole dataframe. Appreciate your guidance on the same :)

Answer (score 0):

I was  led to believe it is generally best to avoid apply and use  standard python such as list comprehensions to loop over columns -  particularly if the frame is very large. E.g. my solution for the above would be something like:

```
counts=(pl.concat([sample_df.select(pl.col(col).value_counts())
               .unnest(col).rename({col:"value"})
               .with_columns(column=pl.lit(col)) for col in 
sample_df.columns])
)
```